# Не подключается bootstrap в шаблоне сайта

Tags: php, html5, bootstrap, link

Здравствуйте!
Делаю сайт на PHP по шаблону MVC с ЧПУ. Создал страницу шаблона сайта, подключил библиотеку bootstrap. При открывании шаблона в браузере напрямую - все работает. 
Теперь сделал контроллер и метод в нем, который инклюдид тот же шаблон. Каким бы способом не забивал путь к библиотеке - ничего не работает.
[[image: Отображение в браузере[][1][1]]

[image: Структура проекта и файл index.php]
[image: Файл шаблона _layout.php]

Answer (score 0):

У вас таблица стилей с обратными слешами "\" измените их на нормальные "/"

Comment: Это из переменной ROOT. Если путь прописать без нее - все равно не работает...

Comment: @МихаилВишневецкий вы посмотрите как браузер отображает, с обратными \, соответственно ничего не работает,в  network 100% стиль не подгружен. Так ваш php не отработает,хотите чтоб норм пыха отработала  <? echo Тег с атрибутами !!!

Comment: Ждал целые сутки, чтобы вернуться с работы и попробовать. Но, все бесполезно )))

Comment: Ввел так: <?php echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'. ROOT .'libs/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css" />'; ?> В инспекторе: <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/xamp/htdocs/itblog/libs/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css">
undefined
</link>

Comment: И даже так: <?php echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/xamp/htdocs/itblog/libs/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css" />'; ?> В инспекторе: <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/xamp/htdocs/itblog/libs/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css">
undefined
</link>